# How do I select and group query results of four MySQL Tables?

Tags: mysql

The tables look like this:

```
companies
companyid   name             description

stations
company_id  province_id

provinces
provinceid  country_id      province

countries
countryid   country
```

How do I show the number of companies in each country?

I tried:

```
SELECT country, COUNT(companyid) 
FROM companies 
LEFT JOIN stations ON company_id=companyid 
LEFT JOIN provinces ON stations.province_id=provinces.country_id 
LEFT JOIN countries ON provinces.country_id=countryid 
GROUP BY country
```

But what I am getting is the country name plus the number of stations in that country instead of total companies in each country.

Comment: group by the company id as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT country, COUNT(distinct companyid) 
FROM stations 
JOIN provinces ON stations.province_id=provinces.country_id 
JOIN countries ON provinces.country_id=countryid 
GROUP BY country
```

1.you dont need to use left join, because there must be no id miss in join
2.If a company can setup more than 1 station in a province or a country, you should use the `distinct` keyword to tell the sql count duplicate items only once in the same group
3.If you dont need the infomation only from company name table,just dont join it